# What parameter in orgtbl-to-latex to set column width?

Tags: latex, org-table, orgtbl

I am trying to set the alignment width of columns in latex. I am using orgtbl's `orgtbl-to-latex`

I want to override the resultant

```
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
```

to something like

```
\begin{tabular}{rlccp3 cm)}
```

What is the argument of the translator function `orgtbl-to-latex` that do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:splice` argument appears to be meant for this purpose.  When non-nil, it omits the environment from the table-receiver block, which gives you the opportunity to write it manually.  For a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rlccp{3cm}}
% BEGIN RECEIVE ORGTBL foo
ipsum & curabitur & lacinia & pulvinar & nibh\\
ipsum & curabitur & lacinia & pulvinar & nibh\\
% END RECEIVE ORGTBL foo
\end{tabular}

\begin{comment}
#+ORGTBL: SEND foo orgtbl-to-latex :splice t :skip 0
| ipsum | curabitur | lacinia | pulvinar | nibh |
| ipsum | curabitur | lacinia | pulvinar | nibh |
\end{comment}

\end{document}
```